# A simple method to secure a simple read-only API

Tags: php, apache, api, http, authentication

I have built a simple read-only API for our database, so that users can retrieve data from our database.

For example, the URL "http://xxxxx/getAllProfiles" will return a JSON result containing all profiles stored in the database.

The API is read-only, it is only implemented with some 'select' SQL queries. Thus the user cannot modify any of the data in the database via the API.

My company worries the API will be exploited by some random bots online, and has been asking me to build a security mechanism for this API. (It is worried if there is no key or something that prevents anyone from accessing the URL, our server would be visited too much. It is a small server.)

What would be the simplest secure mechanism that I can implement, using PHP? (We are also using Slim for the API, Amazon EC2 server with Ubuntu and Apache running on it, if this helps.) Preferably it can be implemented without the use of any database on server or client side.

If there's anything not clear, please let me know, I'll clarify.

Thanks.

Add:
Thanks for the comments.
Is there a way to NOT use a database? Like a smart way to generate a key or something... I'm thinking I'll provide a page so that user can input the domain, and an algorithm will convert this domain to a key. Then, for each request, the user should include this key. The server will grab the domain from the request header and use the same algorithm to calculate again. If the two calculated key matches, the request is accepted. I think this, at a minimum level, ensures that at the beginning there must be someone to input the domain and get the key, thus filtering some random bots out?
I am not sure if this is secure (at all)? But it sounds to me like it can filter out something.

Comment: What about using basic HTTP Authentication?

Comment: Check here? http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19930/how-do-i-secure-my-rest-api

Comment: Take a look at Apache's `mod_ratelimit`.

Comment: @JayBlanchard That's not true. None of the common PHP MySQL interfaces will allow what Little Bobby Tables did, because they don't allow multiple queries in a single call.

Comment: Only `mysqli_multi_query()` would allow it.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar - you're absolutely right. I was erring on the side of caution.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to NOT use a database? Like a smart way to generate a key or something... I'm thinking I'll provide a page so that user can input the domain, and an algorithm will convert this domain to a key. Then, for each request, the user should include this key. The server will grab the domain from the request header and use the same algorithm to calculate again. If the two calculated key matches, the request is accepted. I think this, at a minimum level, ensures that at the beginning there must be someone to input the domain and get the key, thus filtering some random bots out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this question when I know very little about web development. 
There are many ways to secure a REST API, e.g. JWT, Cookie, Basic Auth, etc.